# Solve $ | 2x+4 | > |x-1| $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I know there are many ways to solve it, but i want some help to understand why it is not working specifically on this way:

[image]

a)For $\,\,x<-2$, the inequation becomes:

$-2x-4>-x+1 \Longleftrightarrow 2x+4 < x-1 \Longleftrightarrow x<-5$

Therefore $x<-2\,\, \wedge\,\, x < -5 $ has the solution set $Va = ]-\infty , -5[ $

b-)For $-2<x<1  $ the inequation becomes:

$2x+4>-x+1 \Longleftrightarrow 3x>-3  \Longleftrightarrow x>-1$

Therefore $-2<x<1\,\, \wedge\,\, x>-1 $ has the solution set $Vb = ]-1 , 1[ $

c) For $x>1  $ the inequation becomes:

$2x+4>x-1 \Longleftrightarrow x>-5$

Therefore $x>1\,\, \wedge\,\, x>-5 $ has the solution set $Vc = ]1 , \infty[ $

Then, the solution set $V = Va \, \cup\, Vb \, \cup \, Vc$ will be:

[image]

$V = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x<-5\,\, \lor \,\, -1<x<1 \,\,\lor \,\, x>1\}$.

But the correct answer should be $ V = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x<-5\,\, \lor \,\,  x>-1\}$.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When taking off the absolute values, you should also include the edges.

So your 3 cases should be:

- a)$x\le-2$
- b)$-2\le x\le1$
- c)$x\ge1$

Or else you could use 5 cases. The 3 cases you already have, and then you will have to check x=-2 and x=1 (i.e. replace x with these values and see if the inequality is true).

Comment: Correct. But i think b-) should actually be $-2 < x < 1 $  because otherwise it will leads to $0 > 0$

Comment: $0\gt 0$ is okay, think of the uniqueness of a fixed point of a contraction map.

Comment: these values will be discarded when you solve the inequality. It is not wrong that when you take off the absolute value, it stands for both of these values.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the three cases

- $x < -2$
- $-2 < x < 1$
- $1 < x$

do not cover the entire real line: you have omitted the cases $x=-2$ and $x=1$. Thus, you have only found the solutions that fall into one of these three categories, and your analysis says nothing about whether or not $x=-2$ or $x=1$ is a solution.

You could finish the problem by testing the remaining two cases individually, or you could revise your work to split the line into the cases

- $x \leq -2$
- $-2 \leq x \leq 1$
- $1 \leq x$

If you really prefer, you can insist on making the three cases disjoint.

Ultimately, it doesn't really matter how you go about splitting the line into cases, as long as every real number is covered by at least one case.

Splitting into five cases (your original three, and the two missing points) has the advantage of being somewhat more systematic: breaking things up into open intervals and boundary points is more frequently applicable, and if you get into the habit of (correctly!) dividing the line up like that, you will ultimately stop forgetting about the individual points more quickly.

Splitting into the three cases I mention is, in my opinion, a little cleaner, as the closed intervals match more closely with the behavior of the absolute value. And having the cases overlap at the endpoints gives you a little bit of extra chances to check your work, by seeing if you get the same result for the endpoint in both of the cases it borders.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is (almost) completely correct, its just that $-1\lt x \lt 1 \lor x\gt 1$ is exactly the same as $\{x\gt -1\}\setminus\{1\}$.

And thinking about it, it's because you didn't consider the case $x=1$, you just considered $x\lt 1$ and $x\gt 1$.

Comment: \lor=$\lor$ (logical or), \land=$\land$ (logical and)

Comment: @ellya  I did not realize that the roots should be considered. But I believe in this case we should not consider both roots, because otherwise it will lead to 0> 0

Comment: $0\lt 0$ is completely okay :), it's even part of the proof for a unique fixed point of a contraction map

Comment: really? why is it? i mean, if it is $0 \leq 0$  then i will agree to be true

Comment: Take a contraction map $T$, so $d(Tx,Ty)\le q\, d(x,y),q\in[0,1)$, now assume there are two fixed points $x_1,x_2$, then we have:

$0\le d(x_1,x_2)=d(tx_1,Tx_2)\le q\,d(x_1,x_2)$

$\Rightarrow 0\le (1-q)\,d(x_1,x_2)\le 0$, which can only hold if $d(x_1,x_2)=0\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$

But that also gives us: $d(x_1,x_2)\lt d(x_1,x_2)\Rightarrow 0\lt 0$

Comment: @ellya wow, thats amazing!  But the statement $a<a$ is correct just for $a=0$, right?

Comment: Correct! $0$ is a weird and wonderful thing

Comment: @ellya but is $0 > 0 $ also true? No, right?

Comment: since $0\lt 0$ and both values on either side of the inequality are the same, we can just flip it, i.e. $0\lt 0\Rightarrow 0\gt 0$

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i missed that. But why does wolphram alpha says that $0<0$ is false? http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3C0&x=0&y=0

Comment: Because $0$ is a least element, i.e. it is smaller than all other elements and thus smaller than itself, which kind of violates "$\lt$".